# Adding static part of URL before and after the dynamic reference

Tags: xml, image, hyperlink

This snippet is from a plugin I'm using which imports .XML feed I can get from another website. Problem is, I want to import the feed's remote images as well, but their .XML files doesn't include the complete URL to the remote image itself.

But, the XML does include a reference code like

```
<reference><![CDATA[2519251254]]></reference>
```

Where 2519251254 is the code to get to the remote image they're offering. This can be done by adding:

```
http://www.DOMAIN.nl/store/1/store/2519251254.jpg
```

Where the number is the reference from the XML feed.

Here's the code that's about the remote-image configuration inside the plugin I'm using.

```
        //remote images.
        if ($settings['remote_images']) {
            foreach (array_merge($settings['field_names']['product_image'], array($settings['field_names']['image'])) as $image) {
                if (!empty($raw_prod[$image])) {
                    if (empty($settings['image_subfolder'])) {
                        $settings['image_subfolder'] =  '/';
                    }
                    $raw_prod[$image] = $this->model_tool_total_import->fetchImage($raw_prod[$image], $settings['image_subfolder']);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple example:

```
$ref = $imageId;
$url = "http://www.test.com/".$ref.".png";
```

So you might do this: (if $this->model_tool_total_import->fetchImage($raw_prod[$image], $settings['image_subfolder']) currently is returning the reference you're talking about)

```
//remote images.
    if ($settings['remote_images']) {
        foreach (array_merge($settings['field_names']['product_image'], array($settings['field_names']['image'])) as $image) {
            if (!empty($raw_prod[$image])) {
                if (empty($settings['image_subfolder'])) {
                    $settings['image_subfolder'] =  '/';
                }
                $tmp_image = $this->model_tool_total_import->fetchImage($raw_prod[$image], $settings['image_subfolder']);
                $raw_prod[$image] = "http://www.test.com/".$tmp_image.".png";
            }
        }
    }
```